# Dishwasher part identification

Tags: dishwasher

This dish washing machine piece seems to be leaking (in red). My mom wants to change the dishwasher but I want to try and replace it if it isn't to complicated (hoping the leak doesn't come from somewhere else). Do any of you know how this piece is called?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the name. Just go to a site like repairclinic.com and enter the model number of the dishwasher. Then browse through the pictures until you find the part.